# create a user playlist in wordpress like spotify

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, playlist

my users need to create their own paly list amoung the music I have uploaded to my wordpress site and be able to play them. is there any plus in that can do that?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode

Good luck

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question (which in turn is off-topic for SO).